# Cannot load a hibernate object from database with timestamp

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I have a hibernate mapping with a composite primary key consisting of a many-to-one association and a timestamp. I am trying to check if the object is already in the database before creating a new one. My problemn is that my HQL query does not return the object although it is already in the database and then my save with the exact same values gives me:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:
```

My hql query is this:

```
db.createQuery("from DataCache dc where dc.myObject = :mo AND dc.timestamp = :date").setParameter("mo", this).setParameter("date", timestamp).uniqueResult();
```

Query works without the timestamp part. I have tried to add TimestampType.INSTANCE to the setParameter method but nothing seems to work.

DataCache.hbm.xml

```
<composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one name="myObject" column="my_object" class="...MyObject" lazy="false"/>
        <key-property name="timestamp" type="timestamp" column="timestamp"/>
</composite-id>
```

I am using MySQL 5.6 and Hibernate 4.1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to a bug in my code where the myObject was not loaded from the current hibernate session. To avoid problems with concurrency I used two sessions and the myObject entity was loaded in different session than where I made the hql query.

I got rid of the exception by loading the entity in the current session with:

```
myObject = (MyObject)db.get(MyObject.class, myObject.getId());
```